# How can I stop the function recursion in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, c, xcode

I have one text field.

Below function is attached to an UI event "editing changed" from txtfield's IB.

The function is recursive as obvious I am changing the textfield so it will call

again and again is there any thing , I can stop the function after calling it once.

So,I want to stop this looping function..

```
-(IBAction) testEvents:(id) sender
{ 

    txtEditAmount.text=[txtEditAmount.text substringToIndex:([txtEditAmount.text length]-1)];




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using that event callback, try implementing the `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldDidEndEditing:`, like so:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:
                      [txtEditAmount.text length] - 1];
}
```

So it will cut off the last character only when the user stops editing the field. Depends what you're trying to do though, I guess. If you're trying to backspace whatever they type, for example, a password field which stays blank but still captures the characters the user types, instead implement the protocol method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField
  shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
  replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    [enteredString appendString:string]; // store the character the user typed
    return NO; // leave the field blank
}
```

Comment: It is absolutely a good way to use this method, and simplified my work really thanks...

Answer (score 3):

My variant

```
-(IBAction) testEvents:(id) sender
{ 
    static BOOL flag = NO;
    if (flag) {flag=NO; return;}
    flag = YES;
    txtEditAmount.text=[txtEditAmount.text substringToIndex:([txtEditAmount.text length]-1)];
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, It works nicely,But I have found a good way which matches my requirements,Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a static boolean.

```
-(IBAction) testEvents:(id) sender
{
    static BOOL programmaticallyChanged=NO;
    if(programmaticallyChanged) {
        return;
    }
    programmaticallyChanged=YES;
    txtEditAmount.text=[txtEditAmount.text substringToIndex:([txtEditAmount.text length]-1)];
    programmaticallyChanged=NO;
}
```

Comment: Does `testEvents:` will be called between `programmaticallyChanged=YES;` and `programmaticallyChanged=NO;`?

Comment: @Nekto: That's what the question implies.

Comment: Yes, of course, I wasn't sure that that `testEvents:` would be called between that assigns. If it will - then great solution

Comment: @nekto : I have mentioned that testEvents is attached to UI Event editing did changed..so working thanks..really..

Answer (score 1):

Implement this method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  return YES;//it will allow edit to you if NO it will not allow to you
//return NO;when don,t want call that
}
```